# How to implement location search using google maps in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am building an iOS app.I am using storyboards to build the screens and i have integrated google map in my project.

I want to get location where tap in the map and want to show that location in a label like in Airbnb app.I’m unable to do that,could someone help.

here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];
   mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

   mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
   self.view = mapView_;
   GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
   marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
   marker.title = @"Sydney";
   marker.snippet = @"Australia";
   marker.map = mapView_;
}
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: do you understand my response? anything still unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `GMSMapViewDelegate` protocol for that. Precisely, the method `mapView:didTapAtCoordinate:` will do what you require and detect a tap on the map and giving you the tap's coordinate.

To use the method, add the following line in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
mapView_.delegate = self;
```

Then in the same class implement the method:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{
   // coordinate contains your coordinate :)
   NSLog(@"did tap at coordinate: (%f, %f)", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
}
```

**Update**: To add a marker you can do the following:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{
   // coordinate contains your coordinate :)
   NSLog(@"did tap at coordinate: (%f, %f)", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);

   // Create the marker and add it to the map
   CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
   GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
   marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
   marker.map = mapView_;

   // Zoom into the current location
   GMSCameraPosition *cameraPosition = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:position zoom:15.0];
   [mapView_ animateToCameraPosition:cameraPosition];
}
```

Comment: thanks @nburk i'm getting latitude and longitude but how i can display the area name.

Comment: well you have to add a marker to the map and set the title of that marker. what exactly is your problem? getting the area name or displaying something on the map with a marker?

Comment: i updated the answer with the code to add a marker and also zoom into the tapped location

Comment: I have applied your code and getting markers on tap but not getting area name,i just changed this line CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( coordinate.latitude,  coordinate.longitude); when map zooms on tab there is nothing only greyish map is shown

Comment: 1. sorry there was a small error, the line indeed has to be `CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);`

Comment: 2. you can add the title by calling `marker.title = <title>` where <title> is the string variable that contains the name of the area

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64727/discussion-between-daljeet-and-nburk).